# Can not get cookie value in Spring boot

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, cookies

When user is logged in I save JWT token in cookies using Javascript

```
document.cookie = "token=Bearer " + userDetails.loginSuccess.token;
```

But when i make the request to Spring boot Controller i can not find the cookie

```js
 public String home(@CookieValue(value = "token") String token,
                    @PathVariable String businessId,
                    @PathVariable String cartId, ModelMap model,
                    HttpServletRequest request) {}
```

How can i get it cookie value in Controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get the HTTPServletRequest object in the controller and then get the cookies like this.

```
 public ResponseEntity<String> home(
  HttpServletRequest request,
  HttpServletResponse response,
  @RequestBody Map<String, String> params) {
      request.getCookies();
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Should be name="token" not value

```
public String home(@CookieValue(name = "token") String token,
                    @PathVariable String businessId,
                    @PathVariable String cartId, ModelMap model,
                    HttpServletRequest request) {}
```

Comment: `name` and `token` are aliases to each other so they're interchangable.